# Ext.slider.Multi constrainThumbs bug?

Tags: javascript, extjs, slider, extjs4.2

I have a [ExtJS multi slider](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.slider.Multi) for which I have 4 thumbs (slide picker) but its not working as expected

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    
    Ext.create('Ext.slider.Multi', {
        width: 200,
        values: [20, 40, 60,80],
        increment: 5,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        constrainThumbs: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

1. Click 4th thumb and move to extreme right side.
2. Click 3rd thumb and move to extreme right side, do same for all other thumbs.
3. Now all your thumbs will be at right side.
4. Now try to move the thumbs one by one towards left.

*This functionality is weird!!*

> `constrainThumbs` is `true` and that is the requirement, because *thumbs should not pass each other*

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/3bhwL/)**

Comment: this could be a bug. Did you raise this in sencha forum as bug? they will confirm whether it is bug or not.

Comment: @SridharBoganathan no I din't, any links for bug report?

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?80-Ext-Bugs, here you have to explain in detail and share your code. You have to include environment in which you are facing this issue - extjs version, sencha cmd version if you used to create, browsers (better to test the same with all the browsers you have) and OS.

Comment: thanks @SridharBoganathan I have posted it as a bug http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?281249-Ext.slider.Multi-constrainThumbs-bug